# Vue dynamic ref show dropdown

Tags: vue.js

I am using VueJS and want to use right click event to display the dropdown list. But I have multiple dropdown so need to use dynamic ref. How can I show the dropdown that I want when right click?

```
<div class="info" @contextmenu="handler($event)">
    ...

    <b-dropdown size="sm" text="…" variant="transparent" no-caret :ref="`dropdown-${id}`" :item1="this.item1" :item2="this.item2">
      <b-dropdown-item @click="showDetails(item1, item2)">Send</b-dropdown-item>
    </b-dropdown>
</div>



handler(e) {
  this.$ref.dropdown.show();
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send another parameter to the `handler` function that will be the value of the `$ref` you want to open:

```js
<div class="info" @contextmenu="handler($event, id)">
    ...

    <b-dropdown size="sm" text="…" variant="transparent" no-caret :ref="`dropdown-${id}`" :item1="this.item1" :item2="this.item2">
      <b-dropdown-item @click="showDetails(item1, item2)">Send</b-dropdown-item>
    </b-dropdown>
</div>



handler(e, id) {
  this.$ref[`dropdown-${id}`].show();
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

By the way you can use `.prevent` modifier instead of using the `e.preventDefault`:

```js
<div class="info" @contextmenu.prevent="handler(id)">

// your methods
handler(id) {
  this.$ref[`dropdown-${id}`].show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `e.target` to get the element (button) you just clicked and after that use a switch statement to determine which dropdown to show.